# Database change needed for hosting over Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, hosting

I've developed a product for my customer using ASP.Net MVC 3 and SQL Server 2008 R2. My customer wants me to host it over Azure. The access will be given to my customer's clients.

I found many posts talking about "NO CODE CHANGE REQUIRED FOR HOSTING OVER AZURE" But my questions is

My customer's client's will have there own set of data, how that will get mapped? My current application, if hosted in premise will serve it's purpose to the fullest. What if I need to use the same schema for 100 clients OVER AZURE? Do I need to database schema to address say 100 clients?

Thanks
VJ

Comment: That is correct that no code change is required to host on Azure, but you have not clarified your problem, kindly clarify what your problem is. Do your customer's clients have their own database ?

Comment: No Adnan. The clients don't have their own database. The application has it's own database which will get shared (I assume) across all clients.

Comment: Then there might be no problem...you'll have to allow client IPs if you're applying security plus there is some limit on concurrent connections...so just keep in mind all the factors

Comment: This question sounds like its about how to support a multi-tenant solution. Windows Azure is a platform for hosting applications. As such, its up to you to properly design the solution to support requirements like multi-tenancy. I see you as having two options, a separate deploy of the app/database for each customer, or design the solution to be tenant aware so it manages tenant data isolation itself.